# R: For every unique value in column, search for corresponding string in other column and append

Tags: r

For example data see below. 
Say I have a data.frame with two columns, A and B. A consists of codes. The codes are linked to column B, that contains areas where people can live in. One code may correspond to multiple areas.
I wish to create a file where every row contains a unique code, followed by columns filled up with the areas the code belongs to.

**Example data**

```
        A       B
      <dbl>   <chr>
 1     1483 De Rijp
 2     1483 De Rijp
 3     1483 De Rijp-Gracht
 4     1483 De Rijp-Gracht
 5     1423 Huiswaard
 6     1423 Huiswaard-Noord
 7     1423 Huiswaard-Zuid
 8     1811 Centrum
 9     1811 Centrum
10     1811 Centrum
11     1811 Centrum
12     1811 Overdie
13     1811 Overdie
14     1811 Overdie
15     1811 Overdie
```

What I would like to end up with:

```
       code   area    area_1          area_2         area_3  area_4
      <dbl>   <chr>   <chr>           <chr>          <chr>   <chr>
 1     1483 De Rijp   De Rijp-Gracht
 2     1423 Huiswaard Huiswaard-Noord Huiswaard-Zuid
 3     1811 Centrum   Overdie
```

I know you can get unique codes with `unique(df$A)`, but after that I don't know where to start and what is appropriate.

*edit* dput data:

```
structure(list(A = c(1483, 1483, 1483, 1483, 1423, 1423, 1423, 
1811, 1811, 1811, 1811, 1811, 1811, 1811, 1811), B = c("De Rijp", 
"De Rijp", "De Rijp-Gracht", "De Rijp-Gracht", "Huiswaard", "Huiswaard-Noord", 
"Huiswaard-Zuid", "Centrum", "Centrum", "Centrum", "Centrum", 
"Overdie", "Overdie", "Overdie", "Overdie")), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Could you please include the output of `dput(df)` in your post? In this way we could use your data example. Or `dput(head(df,15))` if `df` has a large number of rows.

Comment: Thanks and edited @StéphaneLaurent, thanks for pointing me to the dput() function. Will use that more often in my questions!

Comment: in your desired output, you have one row for `1811` that lists Centrum and Overdie, but there are 4 instances of that exact combo in `df`.  How do you want to handle duplicates like that?

Comment: You kindly accepted my answer. The one given in @Onyambu's comment is more efficient and more elegant. I would use this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  library(tidyverse)
  dat%>%unique()%>%
     group_by(A)%>%
     mutate(grp=paste0("area_",1:(n())))%>%
     spread(grp,B)%>%
     ungroup()
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      A    area_1          area_2         area_3
* <dbl>     <chr>           <chr>          <chr>
1  1423 Huiswaard Huiswaard-Noord Huiswaard-Zuid
2  1483   De Rijp  De Rijp-Gracht           <NA>
3  1811   Centrum         Overdie           <NA>
```

Comment: Upvote for this nice "tidyverse" solution. I still need to learn that.

Comment: What package are you using for this code? I installed `dplyr` but I get an error for the function `spread`. Edit. `Tidyverse` it is then.

Comment: @HannekeLettinga As far as I know, `tidyverse` is a *set* of packages. `spread` is from `tidyr`, which is imported by `tidyverse`, like `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want ?

```
ddf <- unique(df)

ddfs <- split(ddf, ddf$A)
dddfs <- lapply(ddfs, function(dd) transform(dd, area = paste0("area",1:nrow(dd))))
dddf <- do.call(rbind, dddfs)

library(reshape2)
dcast(dddf, A ~ area, value.var = "B")
```

This gives:

```
> dcast(dddf, A ~ area, value.var = "B")
     A     area1           area2          area3
1 1423 Huiswaard Huiswaard-Noord Huiswaard-Zuid
2 1483   De Rijp  De Rijp-Gracht           <NA>
3 1811   Centrum         Overdie           <NA>
```

Comment: `dcast(unique(setDT(dat))[,.(B,paste0("area_",1:.N)),by=A],A~V2)` When you load the `data.table` package, it comes with the `melt` and `dcast` functions

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu. My solution is a "R base" one.

Comment: @Onyambu You miss `value.var`: `..., A~V2, value.var = "B")`.

Comment: `transform(unique(dat),grp=ave(as.numeric(as.factor(A)),A,FUN=function(x)paste0("area_",x)))` For base R. My aim is to try and get rid of the `lapply` family as much as I can... well i used `ave`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
# Calculate maximum number of areas
noAreas <- max(sapply(lapply(unique(data$A),
               function(x) table(data[data$A %in% x, ]$B)), length))

library(plyr)
# Create data frame
ddply(data, 'A',
      function(x) {
        vec <- vector(mode = 'character', length = noAreas)
        areas <- unique(x$B)
        vec[1:length(areas)] <- areas
        vec
      })
```

All you would need to do is format the final data frame as required (i.e colnames)